# Google Cloud Vision REST API Request Error

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, velo

I want to use the Cloud Vision API to detect LABELS. Using the following code to make a request via my backend file.

```
    import {vision} from 'backend/cloudVision.jsw';

    let url = {
  requests:[
    {
      image:{
        source:{
          imageUri: "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/33aa21_89b30ab70dcb480992ec7b96b316a907~mv2_d_2000_2000_s_2.png"
        }
      },
      features:[
        {
          type:"LABEL_DETECTION",
          maxResults:10
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

export function button1_click(event) {
    vision(url)
    .then( (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

On my backend file cloudVision.jsw I have the POST request setup like below

```
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';

export async function vision(url) {

  const apiKey = "API_KEY_HERE"; 

  const response = await fetch("https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=" + apiKey, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: url
  });

  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    const ret = await response.json();
      return ret;
  }
    let res = await response.json();
    return res;
}
```

However I am receiving a 400 Error "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.\n[object Object]\n ^" when making the API Request.

I believe it may be a problem with encoding but not sure.

Using Corvid for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a problem with how the request is encoded. I'm not familiar with Corvid. Maybe try putting the keys in quotes eg: "requests" instead of requests. It looks like Corvid is adding "\n" so try defining url on a single line.